# Async Sockets, Receive multiple files on same connection

Tags: c#, file, sockets

I have a server that is going to transfer multiple files to a client over a single connection. The packet from server is in the following format:
     unique_packet_id | file_content

I have onDataReceived function which I need to work like this:

```
    public class TRACK_ID {
         public string id;
         public string unknown_identifier;
    }

    List<TRACK_ID> TRACKER = new List<TRACK_ID>();

    public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            log("OnDataReceived");
            SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

            int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn); 

            // .. read the data into data_chunk

                // if seperator found, that means we got an first chunk with the id
                if (data_chunk.Contains("|") == true)
                {
                    // extract unique_packet_id from the data
                    // bind unique_packet_id to an some kind of identifier? how!!??
                    TRACK_ID new_track = new TRACK_ID();
                    new_track.id = unique_packet_id;
                    new_track.unknown_identifier = X;

                    TRACKER.add(new_track);

                } else {
                   // no seperator found - we're getting the rest of the data
                   // determinate the unique_packet_id of the incoming data so we can distinguish data/files           
                   string current_packet_id = "";

                   for(int i=0; i<TRACKER.count; i++){
                       if(TRACKER[i].unknown_identifier == X){
                               current_packet_id = TRACKER[i].id; // we found our packet id!
                               break;
                       }
                   }

                   // now we got our packet_id and know where to store the buffer

                }


             WaitForData..
        }

     }
```

**I need a variable X that will allow me to track where to store each incoming buffer**

If I closed connection for each file, I could bind unique_packet_id to socket_id (socket_id would be X), but since I'm using the same connection, socket_id always stays the same so I have to use something else for this X variable.

Only other solution I can think of is sending the unique_packet_id in each chunk of data. But that seems like not the best way to do it. Then I would have to split the file buffer into chunks and append the id to each chunk. Any other ways how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say if you're using a stream socket or a datagram socket.

If you're using a datagram socket (e.g. you're using UDP/IP) then you will always receive a whole packet all at once, so you can identify the data because it goes with the `unique_packet_id` that was found before the `|` at the beginning of the current packet.

If you're using a stream socket (e.g. you're using TCP/IP) then I think you have a problem. Your packet format isn't delimited or escaped, so how will you know where one packet ends and the next one begins?

If you are using a stream socket, you need to use, for example, a packet format like this:

- unique packet ID (say, in ASCII, terminated with CRNL —­ or whatever you choose)
- content length (same format)
- packet payload

The receiver can find the end of the packet because it knows how many bytes will be part of the payload.

You will also need to be prepared for the case where you get one of your packets in small pieces. For example, your callback function might be called once with part of the unique packet ID, called again with the rest of the header and part of the payload, and again with the rest of the payload and the complete following packet tacked on to the end. Or you may get three whole packets and part of a fourth in a single call to your callback function.

The other possible solution you mention, that of sending the unique_packet_id in each chunk of data, is not possible, because the sender doesn't know how the data will be chunked up when it is delivered to the receiver.

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative response! Let me make sure I got this. I got a buffer (byte array), I do I loop through it (i+=1024) and append packet id and length at the beginning then send it to client. The packet_id would stay the same for all the chunks? it would only differ for each file only, correct?

Comment: You have to prepend that information, not append it. Otherwise the receiving client can't know how many bytes are in the chunk payload. As for `packet_id` staying the same for all chunks of one file, that's how I would do it, but then it should probably be called something like `file_id` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little lost now. By pre-pend you mean I should first send the id and size and then send the data? Will that still let me destinguish from different files? I did append it now and I'm having trouble with chunks as you mentioned. Sometimes I receive half of the id in one chunk then half of the id at the second. How can I avoid this!? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you must prepend the ID and size, not append it. As for receiving half the ID in one chunk and half in the next, that's normal for stream sockets. You cannot avoid it, you must handle it. Hint: use a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) to process incoming bytes one by one, keeping state across calls to your `OnDataReceived` function.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I don't understand: server sends two files from seperate threads at the same time to client - 1. ID_1|34 and ID_2|44 (second parameter is size) and then sends out the chunk (just chunk or ID too?) if just chunk, client receives ID_1|34 waits for more data, but ID_2 packet arrives first with the payload. How does client know that it's actually content of packet 2 not packet 1?

Comment: I'm going to make a simple illustration of the problem in a second, it's hard for me to explain. :p

Comment: Since you are using multiple threads you have to be careful not to interleave data from one chunk with data from another chunk or else you will get exactly the problem you are seeing. Arbitrate access to the socket with a mutex. Write only complete chunks from inside the critical section and flush your output buffer fully before you release the mutex. This is a classic issue with using any kind of shared resource from multiple threads.

Comment: Celada, thank you very much! I think I'm just going to go with a different approach and use individual connections for each file, this seems more complex than I expected.

Comment: can you also help me out @user1015551? here is my case... it's pretty similar, but still unresolved yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740672/java-socket-sending-multiple-files-but-received-a-single-file

Comment: @gumuruh You have a correct answer already on that question. It comes down to the same solution as this question: you have to incorporate into your protocol the length of each file so that the receiver can count bytes and know where in the TCP/IP stream one file ends and the other begins.

Comment: @gumuruh you are commenting on the wrong question, this will be the last reply I will give you over here. But right offhand, I can see that `inp.read(bp, 0, bp.length)` can't be right because it will usually read more bytes than are left in the file on the second and subsequent iterations of the `while` loop...