# Java Socket Sending Multiple Files but Received a Single File?

Tags: java, android, file, sockets, file-transfer

Now this is very strange....
I have two android devices in which both of them operating
one as a Server and another as a Client.

The problem is, When a Client send a file through socket.
Server will receive it fine. But when Client try to send multiple files,
then Server will only receive single file... why is like that?

I already did flushing the socket for each file from the list (client).
But .... Why did the Server (receiver) code, only write a single file as its output?

Please cmiiw.

Here is the code for **Server (receiving):**

```
Socket bSock = serverSocket.accept();

    DataInputStream inp = new DataInputStream(
    bSock.getInputStream());

// reading the code first

int iCode = inp.readInt();

if(iCode == Request.STATE_FILESHARING){

                        // reading how many files will be found
    int manyFile = inp.readInt();
    String dName = null;

    for (int index = 0; index < manyFile; index++) {

    // reading the file name
    dName = inp.readUTF();

    // reading the file size
    byte bp[] = new byte[inp.readInt()];

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(SDTool.getCurrentLocalTransferPath() + "/" + dName);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    // reading the content
    int count;
    int fsize = 0;
    while ((count = inp.read(bp, 0, bp.length)) != -1) {
            fsize += count;
            bos.write(bp, 0, count);

             // this will exist the loop of reading
            if(fsize == bp.length)
            break;

        }

    bos.close();
    fos.close();

    }

}
```

and here is the code for **Client (sending):**

```
socket = new Socket(myServerAddress, SocketServerPORT);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

double dTotalSize = getTotalSize(nList);
int iTotalTransferred = 0;
double dPercentage = 0;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

// sending multiple files state
out.writeInt(Request.STATE_FILESHARING);
// sending how many files required to be accepted
out.writeInt(nList.size());

for (Item o : nList) {
        File myFile = new File(o.getPath());
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        // bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        // set the code, the file name, and then the size
        out.writeUTF(myFile.getName()); 
        out.writeInt(mybytearray.length);


            int len = 0;        int fsize = 0;
            // here is the content      
            while ((len = bis.read(mybytearray)) != -1) {
                    fsize += len;
                    dPercentage = (double) ((fsize * 100) / dTotalSize);
                    dPercentage = Math.round(dPercentage);
                    out.write(mybytearray, 0, len);
                    updateProgressUploadUI(dPercentage); 
            if(fsize == mybytearray.length){
            out.flush();                       
            }
        }


        bis.close(); 
        fis.close();

}
```

Comment: Please tell how the server should know that more files are coming. What protocoll is there between server and client? What does the client send? Please explain that first. Explain the code.

Comment: and when it comes to protocols, consider this http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: i think on the server side, I should put ... this algorithm :
"When it reach the final length of the bytes. It should break the loop of reading the content. And start a new FileIO operation" Am I  right ? @greenapps

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the first file until end of stream, which only happens when the sender closes the socket after sending the last file. So you're seeing all the files as a single stream. You need to constrain your reading loop to only read the exact number of bytes in each file. I've posted the necessary code here many times, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150559/sending-and-receiving-files-on-socket/24151903#24151903).

Comment: i should put the if else inside the reading content of the server method right? and on the client (sender) i should flush every one single file also... am i right @EJP? Please check the updated code above.

Comment: No. That is not the solution. You use writeInt() to tell the server how many files are coming. But you should use writeInt also for every file first. You write an int which tells how many bytes the following file will be. Then the server can just read that many bytes, read the next int and so on. So you have to adapt your protocoll. Thats why I asked you to explain first how this all should work.